# Programming question(death battle) on probability

Tags: math, probability

In a crossover fantasy universe, houin kyoma is up in a battle against powerful monster nomu that can kill him in a single blow. However being a brilliant scientist kyoma found a way to pause time for exactly M seconds. Each second, kyoma attacks nomu with certain power, which will reduce his health points by that exact power Initially nomu had H health points. Nomu dies when his health points reach 0, Normally kyoma performs normal attack with power A. Besides from kyomas brilliance, luck plays a major role in events of this universe. Kyoma luck L is defined as probability of performing a super attack. A super attack increases power of normal attack by C. Given this information calculate and print the probability that kyoma kills nomu and survives. If kyoma dies print RIP.

Input format
First line is integer T denoting number test cases.
Each test case consist of single line with space separated number A H L1 L2 M C. Where luck L is defined as L1/L2. Other number are, as described above

Output
Print probability that kyoma kills nomu in form p1/p2 where p1<=p2 and gcd(p1,p2)=1. If impossible, print RIP without quotes

Example
input
1
10 33 7 10 3 2
Output
98/125

How the probability comes to 98/125?

Comment: While it is a little more amusing, can you formulate it in a way that doesn't have all this fluff?

Comment: Although your question is based on the description in a programming problem, your question is not based on the programming but just on a mathematical justification for the output for one particular input. Therefore it seems that this question would be a better fit on the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once you have added more of your own work and explained just where you are stuck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about practical computer programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 seconds ==> 3 attacks.

Monster has 33 health points.

Normal attack does 10 damage.

Super attack does 12 damage.

==> In order to kill the monster you need to get lucky at least twice out of three attacks.

The probability of super attack is 7/10, the probability of standard attack is 3/10.

Let's check the variants:
If first attack is not lucky, the other 2 must be lucky.
If first attack is lucky, only one of the remaining 2 must be lucky.

==> Probability to kill the monster = 3/10*7/10*7/10+7/10*(3/10*7/10+7/10) = 98/125